# How can I speed up builds for an Android project in Intellij?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have an Android project. In eclipse, if I change one line and rerun the app on my phone, the turnaround time is super fast. On Intellij, it does a full recompile of my project and takes over half a minute. Can this be sped up in any way? Is this a bug or might I have misconfigured something?

Comment: I had the same problem and this is what I did: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14953591/2061594

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build | Make compiles only changed files and dependencies, however if you have a lot libraries in your project, Android dx compiler may take a lot of time to produce the final apk. Verify that you didn't add any extra libraries to the module dependencies.

Comment: I do have extra libraries that I want to use. I believe this is what's taking all the time. 

Is there a way to precompile them and include the dex files in project instead of the jars? I tried using dx from the command line and then replaced the jars with the dexed versions, but didn't get that working.

Comment: No, IDEA doesn't support it, I'm afraid. Please file a feature request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA.

Comment: So until that is implemented, I have to live with the slow builds? What if I replace the jars with their source code?