# Android project taking too long to compile windows

Tags: android, eclipse

I was trying to run the android project for a tablet with huge source code say around above 35 MB with drawables. Its taking nearly 5 to 10 minutes to compile and when i start the Eclipse it takes 5-10 minutes again. Can any one help to resolve this problem. I have Windows, i5 with 12 GB ram configured. Still its costing such a huge time.

thanks in advance

Comment: startup time will depend more on how many SDK versions you have installed rather than you project. Consider removing platform versions that you don't need.

Comment: See the AAPT trick in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335674/speed-up-android-project-build-time-in-intellij-idea/13391537#13391537), it may helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting your `Eclipse` with additional memory assigned as :

```
    eclipse -vmargs -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
```

If you are using Eclipse shortcut, you can update the params through shortcut properties.

Details here: [Running Eclipse with Memory Params](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Frunning_eclipse.htm)

Comment: yogendra thanks for giving replay i have already made that modifications to eclipse.ini file.

Comment: @user1850622: With similar memory? If yes, then probably you have made your Eclipse heavy by installing many plugins. Try after uninstalling the unused plugins.