# IntelliJ skip DEXing modules

Tags: intellij-idea

I am referring to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16282352

Even with just a single third-party module/library loaded in the project setup, IDEA takes incredibly long to build and launch my app. Eclipse is really quick compared to IDEA as it doesn't DEX the other modules every time you build something.

Is there a way to cache the module so IDEA doesn't run through it every single time?

Comment: What version of Intellij are you using?

Comment: This is not normal. IntelliJ normally eclipses eclipse on performance. You're doing something weird. IntelliJ caches everything.